# NPSP: Need field to add connected contact in new Case, and have that connected contact build case history from this

Tags: lightning, npsp

I'm customizing NPSP for a local Women's Refuge Shelter. A woman comes to us seeking help. She is entered in as a contact. Now, we open a case for this incident & I would like to have a field in this case area where the woman's abuser is selected or entered as a new contact within that particular incident. The abuser person's contact record now begins to compile a case history, if they are named by the client who is seeking help from our organization.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to create a look-up field to contacts to create the 2nd contact (alleged abuser). This won't be a primary relationship to the case like the person who is seeking help from you. You may want to create a list of "related contacts" if you're going to create this kind of functionality and want to see them later from the record detail page.